# ConEmu: Unreadable link colors in Far F1 menu

Tags: conemu, far-manager

Wanted to write *colors in Far help*, but the word `help` is not allowed in question title, huh!

Anyway, I'm using the default `ConEmu` color scheme, which is excellent (based on Solarized?). The only problem is, if you press <kbd>F1</kbd> to open Far's help, the links in the TOC are barely readable. Any settings I can change in Far or ConEmu to fix that?

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

Far > F9 > Options > Colors > Help > Reference

Choose readable text color there.

Comment: Sounds great, would love to try, but for some reason my Far has a problem entering that menu. http://bugs.farmanager.com/view.php?id=3318